# Using web api or libraries

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, libraries, asp.net-mvc-web-api

We currently have 1 domain and 4 subdomains using 5 different applications. We are programming in asp.net and we have 6 different solution project. 5 applications and 1 solution for shared back-end.  Each application is deployed with its own dll + shared dll.

Since we are looking to start using asp.net MVC, we are now interested in adding Rest WEB API. Plan is to replace one subdomain app (asp.net web forms) with MVC and instead of using libraries, we want to pull data from WEB API.

My questions are
1) Is it worth changing the concept and use wep api instead of libraries to exchange data between our apps?
2) If so, should we create it as a new app (on new subdomain), or just a middle layer in MVC application exposing only methods we need for MVC app?

Comment: This is only one consideration, but wouldn't switching from compiled libraries to web services result in a slowdown of many, many, many orders of magnitude?

Comment: @user16764 could you explain what do you think it would be slower?